# Best way for adding packages I have the source code of to Android project with Eclipse

Tags: android, package

I am developing an Android application using Eclipse and APT.

Now I need to use the package com.plancake.api.client that uses the org.json.simple package.

I have downloaded them on my developer machine (they are on my Desktop for now):

```
|-- com
|   `-- plancake
|       `-- api
|           `-- client
|               |-- PlancakeApiClient.java
|               |-- PlancakeApiException.java
|               |-- PlancakeListForApi.java
|               |-- PlancakeRepetitionForApi.java
|               |-- PlancakeSettingsForApi.java
|               |-- PlancakeTagForApi.java
|               |-- PlancakeTaskForApi.java
|               |-- PlancakeTasksFilterOptions.java
|               `-- Utils.java
`-- org
    `-- json
        `-- simple
            |-- ItemList.java
            |-- JSONArray.java
            |-- JSONAware.java
            |-- JSONObject.java
            |-- JSONStreamAware.java
            |-- JSONValue.java
            `-- parser
                |-- ContainerFactory.java
                |-- ContentHandler.java
                |-- JSONParser.java
                |-- ParseException.java
                |-- Yylex.java
                `-- Yytoken.java
```

What's the best way to add them to my Android project in Eclipse?

What I would prefer is a command-line simple solution just to understand what happens under the hood.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be doable using libraries??

--->Project Properties--->Java Build Path--->Libraries.

Might be worth looking into.